# How to make a TableLayoutPanel like resizable div in html

Tags: html, winforms, css

Consider this simple HTML code:

```
<div class="part">
    <div class="part-header">
        A fixed-height for header
    </div>
    <div class="part-body">
        The number of inner divs depends on the foreach result.
        I want this to fill the remaining space
        <!-- ko: foreach... -->

    </div>
</div>
```

The above code is going to use as a `part` component into several places.

I want it to reshape in different height sizes of its parent.

Using a CSS like this would help:

```
.part-body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

But it overlays the parent because of existence of the `part-header`.

I want something like Windows Forms Table Layout Panel, with rows `AutoSize, Percent, AutoSize`.

**Question:** How can I set this component in a way that its body height re-sizes to `parent.Height-header.Height` automatically using CSS 3.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `display: table` and `table-row` like this:

```
.part {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.part-header {
    display: table-row;
    height: 30px;
}

.part-body {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

Here is a [demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc95v/). And [another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc95v/1/) with scrolling. And [another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yc95v/2/) with scrolling on firefox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The second jsfiddle is near. But is that possible to have scroll bar just on the silver part. So the header stay fixed as inner list scrolls?

Comment: Another problem with it is that you've set the #parent height to 300. But it doesn't affect. As you see the red table ends at the middle of the list.

Comment: What browser are you using? I tried it in Safari and Chrome, and only the silver part is scrolling, the header stays in place. I'm not sure I understand your second comment. Only half of the list is visible because it extends the given 300px height.

Comment: I'm using Firefox. I've checked it on Chrome and it's OK there! In the Firefox the silver part overlays the red rectangle and causes the outer scroll bar to appear!

Comment: Are table and table-row among standard tags in HTML 5.0 and CSS 3.0?

Comment: Yes, those are standard since [CSS 1.0](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp). I try to make it work on firefox...

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
.part {height: 100%;}

.part-header {height: auto;}

.part-body {height: auto;   }
```